# Pygame function text for 3 seconds

Tags: python, pygame, delay

I have a game doing a countdown, at the end of the countdown I want to display the text "Missle Away!" on the screen for 3 seconds. I have the code below but when I run it, the text never displays. If I remove the delay, the text displays but of course it does not disappear after 3 seconds.

```
def missle_call():
    global missle_active
    global active
    while missle_active == True:
        gameDisplay.blit(radarbg, (700, 100)) # clears the countdown text by writing the background image over it
        TextSurf, TextRect = big_text_objects("Missle Away!" , large_base_font) # set font & text 
        TextRect.center = (950, 300) # set location of text 
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect) # render text to screen 
        pygame.time.delay(3000) # continue to show text on screen for 3 seconds 
        gameDisplay.blit(radarbg, (700, 100)) # cover text on display by blitting the background image on it 
        active = False # reset the launch execution to not launched 
        return

    else:
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display is updated only if either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
is called. Further you've to handles the events by [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump), before the update of the display becomes visible in the window:

```py
gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect) # render text to screen 
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.event.pump()
pygame.time.delay(3000) # continue to show text on screen for 3 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you, did not know about pygame.event.pump. Have it working now!